# Move a local sqlite database to a remote server ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, ios5

I am creating an iPhone application using xcode 4.2. I have a local SQLite database that I have created and it works fine on the simulator.

I want to move this database to a remote server so that others with this application can access the data and it can be updated.

Can anyone tell me the easiest way to do this? Or point me in the direction of some good tutorials?

I am pretty new to the whole iPhone programming so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app this would help you

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to "serve" the database from a remote host, vs having the DB resident on the phone, the best way to do this is with a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) protocol between phone and server.